# On the flow of $v(x,y)=(x,y)$ and the Lefschetz number

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, manifolds, differential-topology

> Let $v$ be the vector field on $\mathbb R^2$ defined by $v(x,y)=(x,y)$. Show that the family of diffeomorphisms $h_t:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ defined by $h_t(z)=e^tz$ is the flow corresponding to $v$. That is, if we fix any $z$, then the curve $t\mapsto h_t(z)$ is always tangent to $v$; its tangent vector at any time $t$ equals $v(h_t(z))$. Draw a picture of $v$ and its flow curves. Compare $\operatorname{ind}_0(v)$ with $L_0(h_t)$.

(Note that the original text defines $h_t(z)=tz$, but I used this [errata list](https://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/Guillemin_Pollack_errata.pdf).)

The first part is "obvious" from the picture. Formally, if $z$ is fixed, then the tangent vector of $t\mapsto e^tz$ at $t$ is the derivative of this map at $t$, which is again $h_t(z)$. But $v$ is the "identity" -- $v(z)=z$, so the tangent vector, which is $\frac{d}{dt}h_t(z)=h_t(z)$, is also $v(h_t(z))$. 
But I have a problem with showing that the curve $t\mapsto h_t(z)$ is always tangent to $v$. This means that $\frac{d}{dt}h_t(z)=v(z)$. But this isn't true.

For the second part, $\operatorname{ind}_0(v)=1$ since the corresponding map is the identity. To compute $L_0(h_t)$, consider the map $z\mapsto \frac{h_t(z)}{|h_t(z)|}$ and compute its degree, which is $L_0(h_t)$. It seems this map is closely related to the map in the definition of the index of a (local) vector field (is it the same map?) and it seems the degree must be also 1. But how to show this rigorously?

Comment: You are right, you have already shown that the tangent vector of the curve at the *point* $e^t z$ (that is, for time $t$) is the *vector* $e^t z$.  In general, you should distinguish between *points* (elements of the manifold $\mathbb{R}^2$) and *vectors* (elements of the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{R}^2$).  You are wrong saying that $v$ is the identity:  it is a mapping from the manifold (the affine space) $\mathbb{R}^2$ into its tangent bundle (and in that example, it can be expressed in the natural chart as identity).

Comment: I fixed the first part of the question in accordance with the definition of $h_t$ being tangent to $v$ given on p.135. But this definition doesn't hold when $h_t(z)=e^tz$ as far as I can see (it holds when $h_t(z)=tz$). Maybe the definition should be the original one, $h_t(z)=tz$? But on the other hand with the original definition it seems that the tangent vector isn't $v(h_t(z))$... (@TedShifrin - maybe you could clarify this...)

Comment: Fix $z$.  The mapping $t \mapsto e^t z$ has, for any $t \in (-\infty, \infty)$, tangent vector $e^t z$.  And the value of the mapping for such $t$ is just $e^t z$ (the latter is an element of the manifold $\mathbb{R}^2$, the former is an element of the tangent space $T_{e^t z} \mathbb{R}^2$).

Comment: @user539887: but this doesn't show that $\frac{d}{dt}h_t(z)=v(z)$ (or perhaps this should hold only for $t=0$, in which case this my question disappears). By the way, the same problem shows up in this question [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2730130/a-curve-tangent-to-a-vector-field].

Comment: $$ \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{t + h} z - e^{t} z}{h} = \bigl(\lim\limits_{h \to 0}  \frac{e^{t + h} - e^{t}}{h} \bigr) z = e^t z \quad \forall{t \in (-\infty, \infty)}.$$

Comment: In your question you asked:  "But I have a problem with showing that the curve $t \mapsto h_t(z)$ is always tangent to $v$. This means that $\frac{d}{dt}h_t(z)=v(z)$. But this isn't true."  I just showed you that this is true.

Comment: Sorry, probably I'm missing something, but $\frac{d}{dt}h_t(z)$ depends on $t$ whereas $v(z)$ doesn't. How can they be equal (in the case $t\ne 0$)?

Comment: @user500094: according to definition on p.135 derivative of $h_t(z)$ should be $v(z)$ only at $t=0$ and since is is $e^0z=z=v(z)$ we are done.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}h_t(z) = h_t(z)$ doesn't make sense in the manifold setting. Nor does $\frac{d}{dt}h_t(z) = v(z)$, except for those $t$ with $h_t(z) = z$. For $h_t(z)$ is a point of $M$, and $\frac{d}{dt} h_t(z) \in T_{h_t(z)}M$. The condition that $h$ is the flow of $v$ means that for all $z$ and all $t$ we have $$\frac{d}{dt}h_t(z) = v(h_t(z))\,.$$